# C#, dynamically creating picture boxes?

Tags: c#

For example I use a loop to create a list of "bird" objects with certain parameters.
But I also need each bird object to have a pictureBox on the winform, any ideas, how do I do that, i.e. dynamically create and later delete a pictureBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the first result from googling your question title, which has an example of this:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78037-dynamically-create-multiple-picture-boxes/

Another: http://thechaosrift.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=4387&p=51006

Did you try something already and have a problem?  If not, it's always worth consulting Google to see if you can learn on your own first.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, I kinda didn't find it in google for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code:

```
 list<picturebox>

 Instantiate the one needed 

 Initialize every picturebox that are needed

 Add them to the form (form.control.add)

 If needed remove them from the form, (form.control.remove)
```

Comment: That's Pseudo, PictureBox, List, Controls.Add, Controls.Remove.  And you can't initialise a PictureBox without first instantiating it. :/

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone, I would assume that s/he would know that :-) but i will add it anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `PictureBox` instance, set its properties, and add it to the `Controls` collection of a form or panel.