# How do you code objects created in code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic-controls

I'm using vb.net, and I can't figure out how to code a picturebox that I create in the code.

Comment: Can you please supply more information? What are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: I know how to create a picturebox already, I just want to program it.

Comment: For example, if I was to create a button in code, how would I determine what that button does?

Answer (score 3):

Create a instance of [PictureBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) and Set the properties, events as per you requirement.

follow this SO thread: [C#, dynamically creating picture boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853071/c-dynamically-creating-picture-boxes) and the Picture class documentation link to understand the properties and the events.

For example:

```
Dim WithEvents PictureBox1 As PictureBox

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(16, 48)
    PictureBox1.Text = "RadioButton3"
    PictureBox1.Size = New Size(120, 20)
    PictureBox1.Image = _
        Image.FromFile("c:\vbnet\ch07\pictureboxes\image.jpg")
    Me.Controls.Add(PictureBox1)  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim pic As New PictureBox
    With pic
        .Name = "pic1"
        .Size = New Size(250, 250)
        .Location = New Point(50, 50)
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        .Image = Image.FromFile("C:\flower.jpg")
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(pic)
End Sub
```